# Compilation error when building squashfs tools

Tags: compiling, source-code, patch, makefile, squashfs

I tried to compile *unsquashfs* tool from GPL source, the sources are in the 'squashfs-tools' directory. Executing `make` gives error: `Makefile:2: *** Sqlzma is not defined.  Stop.` As I see, the sqlzma files (sqlzma.h ?) located in another directory, 'sqlzma-3.4-457'.

squashfs-tools directory content: [image]

Makefile:

```
ifndef Sqlzma
$(error Sqlzma is not defined)
endif

INSTALL_DIR = /usr/local/bin

INCLUDEDIR = .

CFLAGS := -I$(INCLUDEDIR) -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_GNU_SOURCE -O2
ifdef UseDebugFlags
DebugFlags = -g -Wall -Wno-unused-variable -O0 -UNDEBUG
endif
CFLAGS += -I${Sqlzma} -D_REENTRANT -DNDEBUG ${DebugFlags}
LDFLAGS += -L${LzmaAlone} -L${LzmaC}

all: mksquashfs unsquashfs

mksquashfs: mksquashfs.o read_fs.o sort.o
    #$(CC) $(LDFLAGS) mksquashfs.o read_fs.o sort.o -lz -lpthread -lm -lunlzma_r -llzma_r -lstdc++ -o $@
    g++ $(LDFLAGS) mksquashfs.o read_fs.o sort.o -lz -lpthread -lm -lunlzma_r -llzma_r -lstdc++ -o $@

mksquashfs.o: mksquashfs.c squashfs_fs.h mksquashfs.h global.h sort.h \
    ${Sqlzma}/sqlzma.h ${Sqlzma}/sqmagic.h \
    ${LzmaAlone}/liblzma_r.a ${LzmaC}/libunlzma_r.a

read_fs.o: read_fs.c squashfs_fs.h read_fs.h global.h \
    ${Sqlzma}/sqlzma.h ${Sqlzma}/sqmagic.h

sort.o: sort.c squashfs_fs.h global.h sort.h

unsquashfs: unsquashfs.o
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) unsquashfs.o -lpthread -lm -lunlzma -lz -o $@

unsquashfs.o: unsquashfs.c squashfs_fs.h read_fs.h global.h \
    ${Sqlzma}/sqlzma.h ${Sqlzma}/sqmagic.h ${LzmaC}/libunlzma.a

clean:
    -rm -f *.o mksquashfs unsquashfs

install: mksquashfs unsquashfs
    mkdir -p $(INSTALL_DIR)
    cp mksquashfs unsquashfs $(INSTALL_DIR)
```

There is also short note from "install" readme:

```
2. Building squashfs tools
--------------------------
The squashfs-tools directory contains the mksquashfs and unsquashfs programs.
These can be made by typing make.  The source files use a local copy of
squashfs_fs.h (included in the kernel patches) allowing the tools to be made
without needing to patch the kernel.
```

Please advice how to compile unsquashfs & mksquashfs binaries (without touching my Ubuntu 16.04 installation).

Edit: link to [source](https://www.cisco.com/web/fw/opensource/64846727/payton_1.3.5.001_gpl-28.tar.gz).

Comment: Do you have a link to the exact source that you downloaded / cloned?

Comment: I added link to source.